# A different view of ListView in Xamarin forms Android and UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.uwp

I write a code for displaying a List of data on ListView. But, when I deploy this code in UWP and Android OS, their behavior is different together. The UWP program works very well and displays all the list data. But, Android output shows the entire list in a single list item with scroll option.

UWP output:

[image]

Android output:

[image]

And my XAML code for showing data:

```
<ContentPage Title="Edit Data">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <TableView Intent="Menu" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
        <TableRoot>
            <TableSection>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <ListView SeparatorColor="OrangeRed" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ImageCell Text="" Detail="{Binding ., Converter={x:StaticResource TimeToTextValueConv}}" ImageSource="car.png" >
                                    </ImageCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </TableSection>
        </TableRoot>
    </TableView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Anybody did ever face this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page setup is telling it to only create 1 cell and put a **ListView** inside of it. If you are wanting a list of `Items`, only use a ListView. Don't put the ListView inside of a TableView.

**Modified Code**

```
<ContentPage Title="Edit Data">
    <ListView SeparatorColor="OrangeRed" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ImageCell Text="" Detail="{Binding ., Converter={x:StaticResource TimeToTextValueConv}}" ImageSource="car.png" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```